# Ionic 4 loses stack pointer when navigating back

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a scenario that needs to navigate to the same route up the stack, that is:

Say I have the following routes: `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`

And I am able to perform this navigation: `A -> B -> C -> D -> B`

The problem is, when I press the back button after that, the page goes straight to the `A` route as whether it had lost the `B -> C -> D` branch when I hit the back button.

It seems a reasonable behaviour for a switch navigation, but when doing a stack based navigation this behavior seems to be a bug.

I've tried using `NavController`, `[routerLink]` and `Router` to navigate and all of them seem to cause the same issue. Somehow it assumes because the route is the same, it should move the tip of the stack to that point.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic4 the navigation stack is controlled behind the scene. So when you route to a new page, it automatically does the stack push/pop. If it sees that the route is **new** then it simply **pushes** the page to its stack. And if the route is **already visited** then it **pops** to that page.

So if you have your navigation stack as `A -> B -> C -> D`, and then visit page `B` then Ionic sees that B is already present in the stack. so it just **pops pages D and C** and **does not push** a new B to the stack. So your new stack is `A -> B`.

Comment: Yes, I already know that, it's kinda what I described in my question, but how to prevent it is what I'm trying to figure. I need to be able to push visited routes up the stack and not pop to the visited one :(